# Convert byte array to char array in C

Tags: c

So I am reading from a `.img` file byte by byte as seen here:

```
void print_img_section(FILE * f, int start, long int size, char * target_file_name)
{
    unsigned char list[size];

    fseek(f, start, 0);
    if (fread(list, 1, size, f) <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "problems reading directory from image\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

I want to somehow compare `target_file_name` with `list` to see if they match. However, list is array of hex values i.e {AB, 1E, 16} so I was wondering there was a way to convert `list` to a char array in order to compare the two (or if there was any other way you can see to do this task).

Thanks so much for your help in advance!

EDIT:

SOLUTION THANKS TO: Iharob Al Asimi

```
void print_file_name(FILE * f, int start, long int size)
{
unsigned char list[size+1];
char * test = "alphabet_short.txt";

fseek(f, start, 0);
if (fread(list, 1, size, f) <= 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "problems reading directory from image\n");
    exit(1);
}

else {
    list[size+1] = '\0';
    if (strcmp(list, test) == 0) {
        fprintf(stdout, "they match!\n");
    } 
}   
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `list` contains a **string** with hex representations of bytes? If not, this is unclear: `char` and *byte* are synonymous in C.

Comment: What is the contents of `target_file_name`? What does it point to? Does it point to an array of separate bytes (similar to `list`) or to a string?

Comment: First, welcome to #c, we're not generally a friendly bunch, sorry about that, and keep at it, it's a wonderful experience :) byte and char is the same in c. Are you sure you want to compare the char array "target_file_name" with the contents of uchar array "list" ? Also, nothing is "stored in hex".

Comment: @DusteD: indeed, the median vote count on [tag:c] questions seems to be below zero. It's rather tough for newbies to program in C.

Comment: Thanks so much for the interest in helping guys. 

@Iharob Al Asimi has the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `fread()` takes `void *` as it's first parameter so you can simply declare `list` as `char list[size];` and then use `strcmp()`.

But to do so, you need to `'\0'` terminate `list`, like this

```
void
print_img_section(FILE *f, int start, long int size, char *target_file_name)
{
    unsigned char list[size + 1];
    size_t readsize;

    fseek(f, start, 0);
    if ((readsize = fread(list, 1, size, f)) <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "problems reading directory from image\n");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        list[readsize] = '\0';
        if (strcmp(list, target_file_name) == 0) {
            fprintf(stdout, "they match!\n");
        } 
    }
}
```

Don't forget to `#include <string.h>`.

Comment: I don't think it's safe to assume that `target_file_name` or the file don't contain any null characters?

Comment: @Groo It is reasonable to assume `target_file_name` is a string and so has 1 and only 1 null character of concern -  even with OP's imprecise wording.  With `list[readsize] = '\0';`, `list` has at least 1 null character.  The presence of extra null characters will not make for an unexpected `strcmp()` result.

Comment: @chux: I am not sure if it's clear that OP understands this and it's not just a poorly named parameter. I also don't know the `.img` file structure, so I don't have a clue what he is reading from the file either, just wanted to mention the issue with `strcmp`.

Comment: @Iharob Al Asimi Thanks so much! I have been stuck on that part for so long and I didn't even realize the solution would be that simple hahaha!